# How to using callback function to show all month using map method javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am beginner at javascript. I want to understand more **Callback Function** because i have spend a lot time to learning this function but i not yet understood clearly.

This is my code. i want to make new function(callback) to continue this code, and show all month using method **map**

```
const getmonth = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let error = true;
        let month = ["January","February","March","April","Mey","Juny","July","August","September","October","November","Desember"];
        if(!error) {
            callback(null, month)
        } else {
            callback(new error("Data gak ketemu", []))
        }
    }, 4000)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback is the function, which is passed to another function as an argument.
For example:

```
function sayHello(callback) {
  console.log('Hi everyone');
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback(); // execution your function with 3 seconds delay
  }, 3000);
}
```

In your case(I'm not using arrow functions to make it more easy to understand for you):

```
// Lets create a function, which will just print month which is passed as an argument
const printMonth = function(month) {
  console.log(month);
}

// Now we are using map function
// https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

month.map(function(month) {
  console.log(month); 
});
```

The `map` function accepts another function as an argument(it's called callback) and in this function you can do whatever you want with every single element of array. You can also use an `return` to return new array with modified elements of it.

Answer (score 0):

callbacks are often used to continue code execution after an asynchronous operation has completed.

[more about callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

You can create callback function on your code like this.

```
getmonth((err,data)=>{
    if(!err){
        data.map(month =>month);
    }
    return err;
})
```